# Inverse image of $P=\left \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid 0<x+y<1,0<2x-3y<4 \right \}$

Tags: functions, linear-transformations, inverse-function

Considering $$P=\left \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid 0<x+y<1,0<2x-3y<4 \right \}$$ and the transformation $$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\2 &-3 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}$$
I'm looking for the inverse image of $P$. I suppose it has to be something like $$P^{-1}=\left \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid \alpha _{1}<x<\beta _{1},\alpha _{2}<y<\beta _{2} \right \}$$ but I don't know how to calculate the bounds $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$ for $i=1,2$. How I can find these?

Answer (score 2):

When you apply the matrix transformation, what you are doing is transforming the coordinates $(x,y)$ into new coordinates $(u,v).$ In this case,

$$\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 2 && -3\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

which means $u=x+y$ and $v=2x-3y.$ Since $0<x+y<1,$ this implies by the transformation $0<u<1$ and since $0<2x-3y<4$ this implies by the transformation that $0<v<4.$ So the inequalities are $0<u<1$ and $0<v<4.$

Comment: Well I calculated $\left ( 0,0 \right )$,$\left ( \frac{11}{25},\frac{4}{25} \right )$, $\left ( \frac{8}{25},\frac{12}{25} \right )$ and $\left ( \frac{19}{25},\frac{16}{25} \right )$ as the vertices of $P^{-1}$. But I still don't know the bounds.

Comment: I think those are the vertices of $P.$ Let me check.

Comment: I will update my answer because I think I found an easier way.

Comment: Ok I fixed my answer. Let me know if it is unclear still.